# jQuery focus textfield check radio button

Tags: jquery, input, radio-button, focus, checked

I am busy with a little form but i am stuck now.

I have this little code:

```
jQuery('#textinput input').click(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).is(':focus')) {
        jQuery('input:radio[name=open_amount]').attr('checked',true);
    } else { 
        jQuery('input:radio[name=open_amount]').attr('checked',false);
    }
 });
```

This is working half. When i type something in the input text the radiobutton will be checked but if i change my mind and i check some other radiobutton the check is not removed in the HTML code.

And when i type in a value, change my mind and check a other radio button and go back to the input text the radio button won't change automatically then.

So what do i wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `.focus` and `.blur` instead of `.click`

You also have to use `.prop` to set the radio btn

```js
jQuery(function() {

  jQuery('#textinput input').focus(function() {
    jQuery('input:radio[name=open_amount]').prop('checked', true);
  });

  jQuery('#textinput input').blur(function() {
    jQuery('input:radio[name=open_amount]').prop('checked', false);
  });

  //Suggestion: You can add this so that when user clicks on the radio btn, it will fucos on the textbox
  jQuery('input:radio[name=open_amount]').click(function(){
    jQuery('#textinput input').focus();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="textinput">
  <input type="text">
</div>

<input type="radio" name="open_amount" />
```